# Get all rows in a query with limit

Tags: php, mysql

There is a way to get the rest of rows of a query with a Limit clause?

Let me explain, I made one query to show some values on a HTML table, I want to export these values to a .CSV from HTML table and some other values that is not on the HTML table but is retrieving on the query.

The problem is that i'm using LIMIT clause to show the result in HTML in a lot of pages (100 rows per page).

There is a way that I can take all the result to export to CSV instead of repeating the query without the LIMIT just to export all data? Also, I'm using MySQL + PHP. Thanks is advance.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far as SQL and PHP code.

Comment: I didn't tried anything because I just don't have a clue of what can I do, my code is wrong because it's only exporting the first page of the Html Table. The code is huge, I don't know if you'll understand. There is the code: http://pastebin.com/wwPiJhpi

Comment: The code above is actually wrong because it's only taking values of the SQL with the LIMIT clause, when we have 2 or more pages then only the fisrt page is saving in .csv file. I don't know what to do, just running the same query again without the LIMIT, but I think there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use offset

first 100 rows

```
select * from my_table limit 100;
```

second 100 rows

```
SELECT * FROM my_table  LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100;
```

Comment: hmm interesting, but how can I know the exactly number of the offset? I don't know exactly the number of the rows that will be returned

Comment: You don't know only the last qhery  .. otherwise you should know hoe many time you are perform the select and then you can easly calculate the offset .... And you can know when you reach the limit if you get a select count before .

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean export all records to .CSV file, while show only certain records in html page? Why don't you just use another sql?

Or if data is requested through ajax, you can use JQuery table plugin. It 
provides function for export.

Comment: Yeah, the simple way is to run the same query again without the LIMIT clause. I'm just asking if there is an alternative way. Alslo the data isn't request through ajax!

Comment: LIMIT 0, inf.  is this what you want?

Comment: I didn't uderstood, my LIMIT is fixed on 100 rows because I wanna show 100 rows per page in HTML side. But I want all the records (without limit) on the .CSV file

Comment: I am confused. How could you get all records when you only ask for 100? There may be cache data in db, but it still need sql to query them.

Comment: LIMIT $begin, $end
whenever the user click to see other pages I just increment the $begin and $end values, then the page will be reloaded and will query the next results.